# Forward kinematics and dynamics of 3D robot(UR5) arm with sympy

Tags: python, sympy

I am using sympy 1.4 to do kinematics and dynamics of ur5 robot. The express function in sympy seems to return wrong answer.ere The overall aim would be to obtain the Mass, Coriolis, Centripetal and gravity matrices as symbolic expressions. In the attached code, I am trying out a 3R manipulator

In the attached code, I am expecting the position vector of J3 frame to be 0.707106781186548*Base.i + 2.70710678118655*Base.j with respect to B where as the expression returned by the express function has a negative j. 
Any idea where I am making the mistake. Or is there a better way to convert Denavit-Hartenberg representation to get the coordinate frames of the joints?

**edit 1**: I find that the sign convention used in sympy is just the opposite of what I have learned. For example, for a z axis rotation, the rotation matrix of B with respect to A is defined in sympy as

```
 [cos(a) sin(a) 0;
 -sin(a) cos(a) 0;
    0    0   1]
```

Is there a way to go to the sign convention where R_z =

```
 [cos(a) -sin(a) 0;
  sin(a) cos(a) 0;
    0     0    1]
```

without using the transpose function always?

```
from sympy import *
from sympy.physics.mechanics import *
from sympy.physics.vector import ReferenceFrame, Vector
from sympy.physics.vector import time_derivative
from sympy.tensor.array import Array
# Planar 3R manipulator (minimal code)
# DH representation

a = Array([0, 1, 2])
d = Array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
alpha = Array([0.0, 0.0, 0.0])
# q1, q2, q3 = dynamicsymbols('q1:4')
# q = [q1, q2, q3]
q = [np.pi/4, np.pi/4, 0.0,]

x_p = a[1]*cos(q[0]) + a[2]*cos(q[0] + q[1])
y_p = a[1]*sin(q[0]) + a[2]*sin(q[0] + q[1])

print 'x_p, y_p:', x_p, y_p


def transformationMatrix():
    q_i = Symbol("q_i")
    alpha_i = Symbol("alpha_i")
    a_i = Symbol("a_i")
    d_i = Symbol("d_i")
    T = Matrix([[cos(q_i), -sin(q_i), 0, a_i],
                [sin(q_i) * cos(alpha_i), cos(q_i) * cos(alpha_i), -sin(alpha_i), -sin(alpha_i) * d_i],
                [sin(q_i) * sin(alpha_i), cos(q_i) * sin(alpha_i), cos(alpha_i), cos(alpha_i) * d_i],
                [0, 0, 0, 1]])
    return T


T = transformationMatrix()
q_i = Symbol("q_i")
alpha_i = Symbol("alpha_i")
a_i = Symbol("a_i")
d_i = Symbol("d_i")

T01 = T.subs(alpha_i, alpha[0]).subs(a_i, a[0]).subs(d_i, d[0]).subs(q_i, q[0])
T12 = T.subs(alpha_i, alpha[1]).subs(a_i, a[1]).subs(d_i, d[1]).subs(q_i, q[1])
T23 = T.subs(alpha_i, alpha[2]).subs(a_i, a[2]).subs(d_i, d[2]).subs(q_i, q[2])

T02 = T01*T12
T03 = T02*T23


B = CoordSys3D('Base')  # Base (0) reference frame
J1 = CoordSys3D('Joint1', location=T01[0, 3]*B.i  + T01[1, 3]*B.j  + T01[2, 3]*B.k,  rotation_matrix=T01[0:3, 0:3], parent=B)
J2 = CoordSys3D('Joint2', location=T12[0, 3]*J1.i + T12[1, 3]*J1.j + T12[2, 3]*J1.k, rotation_matrix=T12[0:3, 0:3], parent=J1)
J3 = CoordSys3D('Joint3', location=T23[0, 3]*J2.i + T23[1, 3]*J2.j + T23[2, 3]*J2.k, rotation_matrix=T23[0:3, 0:3], parent=J2)

express(J3.position_wrt(B), B)
```

expected result : produces `0.707106781186548*Base.i + 2.70710678118655*Base.j`
actual result: produces `0.707106781186548*Base.i + (-2.70710678118655)*Base.j`

Comment: This is so specific it probably won't get answered, but if you include your import line  will try and run it in debug mode myself see if there are any errors I can find.

I'm running python 3 btw, from your print it looks like you are on 2

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question. Could you please check this again.

Comment: maybe it's b/c i'm on python 3, but even after I import numpy, this doesn't work 'express' expects a ReferenceFrame, not CoordSys3D, and CoordSys3D does not have i,j, k - I switched to B.x,y,x but still not working. Why don't you just define your own transformation matrix and use that?

Comment: thanks. I am going to do define the transformation matrix myself which is far easier I guess.

Comment: yeah sorry I couldn't help